# postgresql combine data from different schema tables if that schema exists

Tags: postgresql, view, schema, union

Need to create a view based on these conditions:

- There are several schemas and tables in the db
- We will create a union from tables from certain schemas
- If the schema don't exist we should skip that schema from our union
- It is given that if schema exists the associated table definitely exists, no need to check that.
- Query should not give error if any of the schema is not created.
- At the time of running query any schema could be missing that is not known until query is run.

So far creating the view using unions is simple enough but I'm not able to figure out what is the best way to include that condition check for schema existence, I'm sorry if this is trivial or duplicate question, any advice or reference could be helpful.

Thanks,
CJ

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql we can use if schema exists:

```
SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'name';
```

Comment: That is fine to check if schema exists, but the question is how do we use this in a select query that is creating union of different schemas?